# Is there some issue with loading the SwiftUI canvas in projects with a build target of iOS 12?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a project with a build target of iOS 12.0. I'm trying to make a small component, only available on iOS 13+, that's in the same project. I have the code wrapped in a `#if canImport(SwiftUI)` check, and each of the classes/structs are marked `@available(iOS 13, *)`. However, the preview canvas will not load. I've tried the usual solutions: restarting XCode, clearing derived data, even restarting my computer. For some reason the canvas just won't show up (it's enabled from the Editor menu). Is there an issue with showing the canvas in pre-iOS 13 projects?

For those curious, here's the code I'm using:

```swift
#if DEBUG && canImport(SwiftUI)
    import Foundation
    import SwiftUI
    import Combine

    @available(iOS 13, *)
    struct TestView: View {
        @State var key: String = ""
        @State var value: String = ""

        var body: some View {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                TextField("Key", text: self.$key).scaledToFit()
                TextField("Value", text: self.$value).scaledToFit()
            }
        }
    }

    @available(iOS 13, *)
    struct TestView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            TestView()
        }
    }
#endif
```

Comment: I don't know what's inside your `canImport` but other just works. Tested with Xcode 11.2. The only I remarked and by default Canvas was On, but was not shown. I tried to clean/rebuild, then turn it on/off... and it appeared.